# Value Error with indexing string despite string present

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to use .index() to search a column of a 2D list and return the location of that line so I can then alter data at that location.  I've been trying to solve a smaller version of this below.

```
data_test = [["2016-12-14T07:39:00.000000Z",0],["2016-12-14T07:40:00.000000Z",1],\
            ["2016-12-14T07:41:00.000000Z",2], ["2016-12-14T07:42:00.000000Z",3]]


string = "2016-12-14T07:39:00.000000Z"
if data_test[0][0] == string:
    print('works') 
else:
    print("does not work")

print(data_test.index(string))
```

The string compare test works, so it isn't anything wrong there, but the index test below returns:

```
ValueError: '2016-12-14T07:39:00.000000Z' is not in list
```

In full operation I will be checking a list of thousands of rows, so I'm trying to avoid just looping through and doing a string comparison at each level.  Any alternatives and help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: `[i for i, a in enumerate(data_test) if my_string in a]` gives a list of the indices of the lists that contain `my_string.`  You can make this a simple `for` loop that `break`s if you only want the first one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data_test = [["2016-12-14T07:39:00.000000Z",0],["2016-12-14T07:40:00.000000Z",1],
            ["2016-12-14T07:41:00.000000Z",2], ["2016-12-14T07:42:00.000000Z",3]]


string = "2016-12-14T07:39:00.000000Z"
for i, data in enumerate(data_test):
    if data[0] == string:
        print("works, index {}".format(i))
    else:
        pass
```

I'm not sure what you want to do with the index, so this could be a vastly inefficient way of going through the list. If you want to transform the list, it might be better to rebuild the list as you iterate through it once and make the transforms as you go.

EDIT:
Since `data_test` is a nested list, `\` was unnecessary, since you can split the data structure over multiple lines. Also you can omit the `else` clause here entirely if you're not rebuilding the list. I just assume that you are.

Answer (score 0):

The string you're looking for is not in `data_test` but in `data_test [0]` so obviously `data_test.index` cannot find it.